# Button within a loop

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm a progress newbie, Below is my current code, with tableNames and fieldnames change to protect the innocent. I want to loop through records in a db, and within that loop include a button, so that while looping through each record one by one if someone wants to change something they can. I have the below code looping through the records fine (without the button element included below) and I have the button element working fine in a separate buffer but when I bring the button into the loop the loop runs fine, but stops after the first button. When I try to continue the button code runs. I want to include a button but it only runs the procedure if it is clicked. If I remove the line 'WAIT-FOR WINDOW-CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW.' the loop continues as I would want and the button appears, however the button is rendered unclickable. Any help apprecaited.

```
define variable cInsertCompany as character format "x(50)" label "Enter the company name:" no-undo.
define variable cCompanyName as character format "x(50)".
prompt-for cInsertCompany.
assign cCompanyName = input cInsertCompany.

for each tableName where client = 'tgl',
each otherTableName where tableName.ref = otherTableName.ref and TableName.name matches  '*' + cCompanyName + '*':
display 
tablename.nrname
tablename.otherfield.

DEFINE BUTTON bUpdate LABEL "Update".
DEFINE FRAME btn-frame WITH SIZE 10 BY 2.
ENABLE bUpdate WITH FRAME btn-frame.

ON CHOOSE OF bUpdate DO:
 RUN btn-mess.
END.

VIEW FRAME btn-frame.

WAIT-FOR WINDOW-CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW.


PROCEDURE btn-mess.
 MESSAGE "Hello" SKIP "You have selected the new button"
 VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
END PROCEDURE.

end.
```

Comment: How are you expecting the button to react? You display the button and it shows it, but then carries on with the loop unless you click the button. You have nothing in your loop to stop on each record and wait for the button to be pressed, or not. Are you expecting the user to acknowledge in some way, that they've finished with the current record? Without the wait-for you have no point in the program to handle events. I think you need pre-select rather than for-each and then manually advance the bufffer based on other events (key up/down) etc.

Comment: I think you're trying to use the wrong technology for this. Lookup queries and browses - they'll enable you to put up a browse window the user can scroll through, and you can then use a button to indicate when a user wants to change a record.

Comment: You'll have kick off a .p 'asynchronous' and have the .p process part of the  loop before returning then you can check if your button was clicked  but 'asynchronous' can be very complicated. It's definitely what you want though to complete what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to demonstrate, again this is a very primitive way of doing this, but using a browse:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt
    FIELD a AS INT
    FIELD b AS CHAR.

DEFINE BUTTON bt  LABEL "Modify".
DEFINE BUTTON btS LABEL "Save".


DEFINE QUERY qr FOR tt.
DEFINE BROWSE br QUERY qr DISPLAY tt.a tt.b WITH SIZE 60 BY 4 .


DEFINE FRAME f
    br bt
    tt.a SKIP tt.b btS WITH THREE-D SIDE-LABELS.

ON 'choose':U OF bt IN FRAME f
DO:
    RUN updateRecord.
END.

ON 'choose':U OF btS IN FRAME f DO:
    FIND FIRST tt WHERE tt.a = INPUT FRAME f tt.a NO-ERROR.
    ASSIGN tt.a = INPUT FRAME f tt.a
           tt.b = INPUT FRAME f tt.b.
    BROWSE br:REFRESH().
    CLEAR FRAME f.
END.

/* Create some test records */
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 1 b = 'first'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 2 b = 'second'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 3 b = 'third'.

OPEN QUERY qr FOR EACH tt.
ENABLE ALL EXCEPT tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.

WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW.

PROCEDURE updateRecord:
    DISPLAY tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
    ENABLE  tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
END PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: Thank you @bupereira, excellent code, exactly what I need, I appreciate the support

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, I endorse what Tim said above. I believe browses are a better way to do this, so you can view the record, select it, then populate a second screen or fields below and then allow the user to go crazy. But if you would like to achieve what you're trying here, I made this mock program to show. It cuts off your where clause and the prompt-for first, but that's not your problem, so I focused on making the button work:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt
    FIELD a AS INT
    FIELD b AS CHAR.

DEFINE BUTTON bt LABEL "Modify".

DEFINE FRAME f
    tt.a SKIP tt.b bt.

ON 'choose':U OF bt IN FRAME f DO:
    MESSAGE 'you pressed a button'
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
END.

/* Create some test records */
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 1 b = 'first'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 2 b = 'second'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 3 b = 'third'.

FOR EACH tt:
    DISPLAY tt WITH FRAME f.
    ENABLE bt WITH FRAME f.
END.

WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW.
```

Now, again: This is not the best way to do this, and I really think two GUI windows could make this so much more professional and presentable. But for the sake of learning, this is how I'd do this.

Let me know if you have any questions, but the code is pretty straightforward, I hope.

Comment: very helpful, much appreciated